# Unity 3d Photon Networking

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, photon

the game i have created is a FPS game and it works with Photon Networking how the game works, when the player shoots another player on the network and kills him that player spawns a coin so a player can collect it and add a point to the score,

BUT!!!!

The problem i am having when the player collects the coin it adds one point to all the people on the network

SO

what i need help with is get the coin to give one point to the player that collected it and not to the whole network

MY CODE:
this is to destroy the coin

```
    public float hitPoints = 100f;
    float currentHitPoints;
    public GameObject coin;

    [RPC]
    public void CoinDie(float amt) {
        currentHitPoints -= amt;

        if(currentHitPoints <= 0) {

            CoinDied();
        }
    }

    void CoinDied() {
        bl_SaveInfo.coinCount++;
        gu.coinCount++;
        CoinDestroy CD = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CoinDestroy>();
        CD.KillCoin ();
       }


    }
```

this is the GUI that displays the points

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gu : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int coinCount = 0;
    float respawnTimer = 5;



    void OnGUI()
    {
        string coinText = "Total Coins: " + coinCount;

        GUI.Box (new Rect(Screen.width - 150, 40, 130, 30), coinText);

    }

    void Update(){
            respawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    public void Clear(){
        if (respawnTimer <= 0) {
            coinCount = 0;
            respawnTimer = 5;
        }
    }


    public void CoinCounter (){
            bl_SaveInfo.coinCount++;
            gu.coinCount++; 
        }



    void ClearScore(){
        coinCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make clear how and where coins count is stored. If you store it on network-synchronized game object representing player then count will increment on each RPC call for all instances of this player object over network leaving other players instances intact.